# Can't insert data to the model from a CSV file upload in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

After I click submit nothing happens, I think because it can't import Mobile from .models so that the **from .models import Mobile** from forms.py is unused. How to import it so that I can upload a CSV file successfully and insert the data to Mobile model.

**forms.py** looks like this

```
import io
import csv
from django import forms
from .models import Mobile



class DataForm(forms.Form):
    data_file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_data_file(self):
        f = self.cleaned_data['data_file']

        if f:
            ext = f.name.split('.')[-1]
            if ext != 'csv':
                raise forms.ValidationError('File Type not supported')
            return f

    def process_data(self):
        f = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['data_file'].file)
        Mobile = csv.DictReader(f)

        for i in Mobile:
            Mobile.objects.create_data(i['mobile_owner'], i['mobile_number'])
```

**views.py** looks like this:

```
from .models import Mobile
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .forms import DataForm
from django.views.generic import FormView


class DataView(FormView):
    template_name = 'sms/mobile.html'
    form_class = DataForm
    success_url = '/upload/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.process.data()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**mobile.html** looks like this

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add SMS Data{% endblock title %}


{% block scripts %}

{% endblock scripts %}


{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'mobile' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label>Upload mobile numbers</label>
  <input type="file" name="data_file">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('mobile', views.index, name='mobile'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi it looks like you have typo in your `form_valid` method.

```
from .models import Mobile
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .forms import DataForm
from django.views.generic import FormView


class DataView(FormView):
    template_name = 'sms/mobile.html'
    form_class = DataForm
    success_url = '/upload/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.process_data()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Change `form.process.data()` to `form.process_data()` and you should be good to go.